# How do you determine if a transaction is unique?

Tags: transactions, bitcoind

I originally thought one could determine whether a transaction is unique or not by its id. However, if you perform `sendmany`, then each of these transactions will share the same id, is that right? In this case, how would you go about determining if a transaction is unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each transaction can have multiple inputs and multiple outputs.  `sendmany` is used when you want to send to many accounts.  It's all still one transaction.

Comment: After putting up this post, I realized that too. I guess having them listed as what seemed to me as different transactions in the `recenttransactions` call confused me a bit. Thanks!